# What's the difference between .DLLs in lib and ref folders in .NET Core 2.0 SDK?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-core

Each DLL in .NET Core 2.0 SDK comes in two copies (they have different content and file size). For instance:

"c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\ref\System.Threading.Thread.dll" (14432 bytes)

"c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Thread.dll" (14352 bytes)

What's the difference between them (and the purpose of having two)?

Comment: That isn't fundamentally different from the full framework, reference assemblies are in c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies and used when you build your program.  Runtime assemblies are in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly and used when you run your program.  The distinction minimizes the risk of an implementation change breaking your program.  .NETCore just litters your disk a lot worse, too many versions, too many assemblies, too many standards and no GAC.   Hopefully they'll get their act together sometime soon.

Comment: That `Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions` is actually only a compatibility shim to allow .NET Standard 1.0-2.0 projects to run on .NET Framework 4.6.1 which doesn't contain all the necessary assemblies and types.. So it is a bit more special than the classic `ref`/`lib` split other NuGet packages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So as Hans Passant already mentioned, "reference" assemblies are used to build programs, which means that this is the assembly that is passed to the compiler as a reference. At runtime however, the implementation might be different. Apart from the framework itself, this may be used by any NuGet package that distributes a single compile-time reference assembly but a variety of implementation assemblies for each target (.NET Core, .NET Framework, MonoAndroid etc.). The `lib` folder in NuGet packages can even be used to add more private implementation assemblies that it doesn't want consuming applications to reference directly.

Reference assemblies only have "stub" methods so that the available API surface is defined and can be inspected by the compiler.

However, you are mentioning the `Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions` folder. It follows the structure of a NuGet package (since that is how it is built and integrated into the SDK), but it has a completely different purpose than a normal library you'd use. It is used to allow .NET Standard libraries to run on partly-compatible versions of .NET Framework. It works by adding the implementation assemblies to the build output - but these are a special as they only forward to corresponding .NET Framework types and add API surface that throws `PlatformNotSupportedException`for types that are available in .NET Standard but not implemented by the .NET Framework. E.g. a .NET Standard 1.* library would reference `System.Object`from `System.Runtime.dll` and a .NET Standard 2.0 library would reference it from `netstandard.dll`. The `Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions` contains both a `System.Runtime.dll` and a `netstandard.dll` that contain type forwarding declarations to forward to .NET Framework's `mscorlib.dll`. This works similar for other types and assemblies.

These assemblies are only added when necessary. .NET Framework 4.7.1 will contain all these assemblies and forwards so no additional files will be added to the build output.

Comment: Would VisualStudio project point to the "ref" folder after adding a nuget package? From the above description, it seems it should. However, in my case (VS2017), the reference is added to the dll in the "lib" folder.